# Path of magnetization in hysteresis curve from demagnetized point

Tags: magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

In Introduction to electrodynamics David J. Griffiths 4th edition, section 6.4.2 in magnetization of ferromagnets, after we reach the saturation point (point b in the image)

> Now suppose you reduce the current. Instead of retracing the path back to
> M = 0, there is only a partial return to randomly oriented domains; M decreases,
> but even with the current off there is some residual magnetization (point c). The
> wrench is now a permanent magnet. If you want to eliminate the remaining magnetization, you’ll have to run a current backwards through the coil (a negative I).
> Now the external field points to the right, and as you increase I (negatively), M drops down to zero (point d).
> [image: hysteresis curve]

What will happen, if we increase the current at point d, i.e. slowly increase it to 0 from point d and keep increasing it, will it follow the same d-c-b path? Or will it follow the a-b path since the magnetization is 0 at this point? What if we turn off the current when we are at point d?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm picturing your question well, but if you increase $M$ at point d then you're basically widening the closed curve while point e and b don't change. This implies that it must change the shape of the curve i.e different path from d-c-b. It would have a path that looks like something-something-b.

One way to look at it is, when measuring impurities in crystals we can use the area under the curve to calculate the loss in energy within the structure of the ferromagnets. To calculate the work we calculate the closed integral of the curve,
$\oint_{M_s}^{M_i} H dM $ where $M$ is the magnetization and ranges from $(−Ms,Ms)$ which are the saturation points of the magnetization and $H$ is the external magnetic field. so changing the magnetization will change the path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I can't understand what you meant by increasing M. The graph given in the book is of M vs I, (not M vs H) as you can see in the picture attached in the question. Basically we have a piece of iron wounded by some wire like an electromagnet, and we plot this curve by changing the current.